# What is the correct way to create a function that takes an ostream reference and prints to it?

Tags: c++, ostream

As the title states, I am trying to make a function that takes an ostream reference and prints to it. The context is that of a Binary Search Tree.

I am not too experienced with ostream, I've only used it once before (only started learning c++ about 3 weeks ago) which I based off a basic template example for operator<< overloading that I found on google.

With my limited understanding I am not sure how I would implement this with a function that I have created.

This is what I've attempted so far based on my limited knowledge,

I first created the reference `void write(std::ostream &out) const;`

Then I tried to create the function,

```
 std::ostream& write(std::ostream &out,node& o){

        out << o.leftChild<< " " << o.val << " " << o.rightChild;
        return out;
    }
```

i.e. o.leftChild and o.rightChild should print the results of the node. o.val is just the data in the node.

The expected results should be something like 1 2 3 4. However, if I attempt to use the reference as I did above, I am given an error message by my IDE saying that *write* *was not implemented*.

However if I wrote the reference as a method, the results are returned as blank.

**UPDATE:** Removed what I assumed was the reference, and I no longer get any error messages.

However result is still zero, which I assume is because of my incorrect implementation.

**UPDATE2:**
What I am trying to attempt precisely, is to have the write function print to it,

The result of calling write on the left child, followed by a space, data from the node, a space and the the result of calling write on the right child (if there is one).

All prior code to this segment I've shown works as intended. For the variables, `data` is a template argument type (`T`), the **left and right childs** are `unique_ptr<node>`s.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with ostream, or references, or binary search trees, or nodes. It's about how you're defining and calling this function, and we can only see part of one of those things.

Comment: So what would the right way to define and call the function be?

Comment: Is it only IDE's error message, or compiler's? If the former, ignore it, if the latter, then [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the only thing i guess as long as he didn't provide scope operator and trying to access member data is this function is either declared  friend of his class otherwise the member data are public scoped

Comment: @Raindrop7 All my member variables are public scoped for this segment of the code. And I've both tried declaring friend and not friend. Sorry if I don't make much sense...I still don't have a strong understanding of c++....

Comment: "So what would the right way to define and call the function be?" We don't know. It depends on the context in which the function is declared. As others have requested, show moar coedz.

Comment: you should add code rather than blablabla

Comment: what do you mean with reference?? 'function prototype'?

Comment: @KyleA Please, give us CODE. More code. We need code. Without it we are wandering in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `write()` declaration is declaring a method in a class (presumably the `node` class), but you are not implementing the *body* of that method.  That is what the compiler is complaining about.

Your second `write()` is implementing the body of a standalone function, not the class method.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class node {
    ...
public:
    ...
    void write(std::ostream &out) const;
};
```

```
void node::write(std::ostream &out) const {
    if (leftChild) {
        leftChild->write(out);
        out << " ";
    }
    out << val;
    if (rightChild) {
        out << " ";
        rightChild->write(out);
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
node n;
...
n.write(std::cout);
```

```
unique_ptr<node> n(...);
...
n->write(std::cout);
```

If you want to implement a standalone function, it would look more like this:

```
class node {
    ...
public:
    ...
    void write(std::ostream &out) const;
};

std::ostream& write(std::ostream &out, const node &n);
```

```
void node::write(std::ostream &out) const {
    ...
}

std::ostream& write(std::ostream &out, const node &n) {
    n.write(out);
    return out;
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
node n;
...
write(std::cout, n);
```

```
unique_ptr<node> n(...);
...
write(std::cout, *n);
```

And then you could take it a step further by changing the standalone function into a custom `operator<<` instead:

```
class node {
    ...
public:
    ...
    void write(std::ostream &out) const;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const node &n);
```

```
void node::write(std::ostream &out) const {
    if (leftChild)
        out << *leftChild << " ";
    out << val;
    if (rightChild)
        out << " " << *rightChild;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const node &n) {
    n.write(out);
    return out;
}
```

```
node n;
...
std::cout << n;
```

```
unique_ptr<node> n(...);
...
std::cout << *n;
```

Comment: I've tried doing this a number of ways, but my compiler is complaining about the variables not being declared in the scope.

Comment: @KyleA then please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing your actual code and actual compiler errors. You are clearly doing something wrong, but we can't see everything you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: `void write(std::ostream &out) const;` is NOT reference. It is declaration of a function.

Second: judging from `const` at the end of declaration it is method inside the class. Then you have to use scope operator (`::`) while defining method outside class body.

As for "blank results" nothing can be said without more code.